# EXCEL: When dragging cells to the right I need to use information stored in columns not rows (Not sure how to ask this properly)

Tags: excel

It's probably a simple problem, but I did not even know the keywords to google it ;/. Let's say I have this data :

[image]

Now I also have this litle formula:

[image]

If I know drag the C cell to the right, Excel will attempt the following caluclation:

=2+B1

What I want him to do is to attempt this calculation

=2+A2

Of course the easiest solution would be to store my initial data in one row instead of 1 column, but it is really inconvenient for me. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `indirect()` method to reference a cell by it's "String identifier", i.e. `"A3"`. When filling out to the right, use `CONCATENATE()` and `COLUMN()` to create your String identifiers `{A1,A2,A3,A4,A5...}` as required:

```
=2+INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A";COLUMN()-2))
```

This will result in the following:

[image]

Side-Node: If you want this for some `x/y`-Grid-Generation, you can also be lazy,
and just insert `=COLUMN()` for every cell from "A1 - Z1" and `ROW()` for every cell from "A2 - A24".

(Or even avoid these at all and directly perform your actual calculation by using `column()` and `row()` as replacement for your x/y.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a combination of the `INDIRECT` and `COLUMN` functions:

```
=2+INDIRECT("A"&(COLUMN()-2))
```

You would paste the above formula into cell `C1`, and then drag across to the right however many columns/rows you wanted to cover.

This would result in the following:

[image]

This works because `COLUMN()-2` returns 1 for the `C` column, 2 for the `D` column, and so on.  Therefore, the formula will be calling `INDIRECT` on `A1`, `A2`, etc. for column `C`, `D`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want relative references to move down as cells are dragged to the right, you can use this:

Instead of:

```
= 2+A1
```

Do:

```
= 2+INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN()+<offset>)
```

Where `<offset>` is whatever offset you need. The offset will change depending on which column the starting formula is located in.

`INDEX` should be preferred over `INDIRECT` because `INDIRECT` is volatile (must recalculate after any change to the workbook) but `INDEX` is not (only recalculated when one of the inputs the formula, in this case `$A:$A`, changes).